# Hide all Rows except matching value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with some data in excel spanning B9:AJ1108 - so multiple rows and columns. I am looking to hide all rows **except** where the value in column B matches the number in cell C5.
I've tried multiple and can only just about get everything to hide but the unhiding is the issue. I understand how to hide all and how to unhide all. What I need help with is how to hide all and then unhide if something matches the value in C5.

Code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Worksheets("Employee information").Range("B9:B1108").Rows.Hidden = False

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Employee information").Range("B9:B1108").Rows.Hidden = True
'Need to put in the argument to search for C5 value

End Sub
```

I would also like this to be button controlled but I don't know if that is a case of creating a module or just code within the sheet?

Comment: Why don't you just use the filter?

Comment: Because the requirement is the use of macros

Comment: Could you share the code you've got so far? The one hiding all rows?

Comment: You can achieve this using filters in a macro. You can assign a macro to a button that filters and un-filters the data. But please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have updated with the code so far (extremely basis as I haven't used VBA before and I would personally use the filter instead)

Answer (score 0):

For unhiding the rows you can use "Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False"
If you want to use a button for the macro to get executed, create a button and excel will ask you which macro you want to get when you click the button.

```
value= Worksheets("Employee information").cells(5,3).value
```

That will give you the value of the cell C5,  now you need to go through the rows and look for this value.

Comment: Thanks, I can get that far and hiding everything, the key is some kind of lookup/match that automatically unhides the single row that is associated to

Comment: I need help to create the VBA that looks at the input to cell C5, searches for it in the data range and then unhides the singular row containing that input

Comment: You can just unhide all of the rows.

Comment: I don't want to unhide all of the rows. I want to unhide *one" row based on it matching the value I input into cell C5.

Answer (score 0):

### Hide Rows Not Containing Criteria in Column

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With Worksheets("Employee information")
        ' Define Criteria (restrict to numbers).
        Dim Criteria As Variant
        Criteria = .Range("C5").Value
        If Not IsNumeric(Criteria) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Define Criteria Range.
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("B9:B1108")
    End With
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim hRng As Range     ' Hide Range
    Dim cel As Range      ' Current Cell (in Source Range)
    Dim CurVal As Variant ' Current Value (of Current Cell in Source Range)
    
    ' Create a union (Hide Range) of all the cell ranges
    ' that do not contain Criteria.
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        ' Evaluate Current Value.
        CurVal = cel.Value
        If IsNumeric(CurVal) Then
            If CurVal = Criteria Then
                GoTo NextCell ' Match found: do nothing.
            End If
        End If
        ' Match not found: add Current Cell to Hide Range.
        If Not hRng Is Nothing Then
            Set hRng = Union(hRng, cel)
        Else
            Set hRng = cel
        End If
NextCell:
    Next cel
        
    ' Hide rows of Hide Range.
    If Not hRng Is Nothing Then
        hRng.Rows.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much VBasic2008! That worked perfectly. Just for my understanding (as a non-VBA but I do code in Java), I was hoping you could answer a couple of questions:
1) by defining it as "Variant" does that tell Excel that it could be a number or text?
2) Does the "For Each cel" sections, are they just like standard coding "for loops"?

Comment: [Variant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type) can contain any [data type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary), even an object (not possible in this case). With [IsNumeric](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) I am avoiding strings and most important error values which would cause the program to fail. For...Each...Next is used to loop through collections. `Range` is a collection of one-Cell `Ranges`.